# Titan DB how to define properties

Tags: indexing, titan

I am new in titan DB and I want to make my own DB.

I want to make two types of vertex: User and Feature. Both of vertex will have indexed property `creation_date`.

Is better way to make only one property type creation_date with index or two `z_creation_date` and `f_creation_date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same property for both vertex types, that's what `.indexOnly()` was made for.

```
mgmt = graph.getManagementSystem()
user = mgmt.makeVertexLabel("user").make()
feature = mgmt.makeVertexLabel("feature").make()
creation_date = mgmt.makePropertyKey("creation_date").dataType(Long.class).make()
mgmt.buildIndex("user_creation_date", Vertex.class).addKey(creation_date).indexOnly(user).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.buildIndex("feature_creation_date", Vertex.class).addKey(creation_date).indexOnly(feature).buildCompositeIndex()
```

Also see: [Label Constraints](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/indexes.html#_label_constraint)